# Template friend error, error: template argument required for 'class LinkedList'

Tags: c++, class, friend

Hi I am tryna friend a class linkedlist in iterator but idk how to do it with templates

```
class Iterator{
    private:
        node<T>* v;

    public:
        Iterator(node<T>* u){
            v = u;
        }

        T& operator*(){
            return v->element; 
        }
        friend class LinkedList;


};

template <class T>
class LinkedList{
    public:
        node<T>* head;
        node<T>* tail;
}
```

I keep getting an error

```
doubleLinkedList.cpp: In instantiation of 'class Iterator<int>':
doubleLinkedList.cpp:214:26:   required from here
doubleLinkedList.cpp:35:18: error: template argument required for 'class LinkedList'
         node<T>* v;
                  ^
```

I have tried alot of things like i putted a template  on top of friend argument but nothing works

Comment: I presume your iterator is also a template. Does it work if you do `friend class LinkedList<T>` ?

Comment: Your code doesn’t define `node` or `T`.

Comment: You can only leave out template arguments within the definition of the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that `LinkedList` is only a friend of `Iterator` if they share the same `T`, then you can forward declare `LinkedList` and make the specialization for `T` a friend:

```
template <class T> class LinkedList;

template <class T>
class Iterator{
    friend class LinkedList<T>;
};

template <class T> class LinkedList{};
```

If you want every `LinkedList` to be a friend of iterator you could also write

```
template <class T>
class Iterator{
     template <class U> friend class LinkedList; // can't use T here
};

template <class T> class LinkedList{};
```

But `LinkedList<double>` being a friend of `Iterator<int>` is probably not what you want. Why not `template <class T> friend class LinkedList` whithout forward declaration? That's because nested templates must have different template parameters: one shadowing the other is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues (see version below to see them applied):

If a template is used (like node) the T must be defined like `template <class T>`

If you reference something, it must have been declared first. Declared is just the type, like `int x;`, `class y;`, or `<template class T> class z;` The definition -- all the details can come later: int x=7 or the full class definition. This is required for `friend` as well.

And, this still gets me sometimes, all classes must end their definition with a ;

```cpp
template <class T> class node; // this has to be declared or defined first

template <class T>class LinkedList; // this is needed to reference as friend later

template <class T> // this is needed because to pass template args, the class must be templated as well 
class Iterator {
    private:
        node<T>* v;

    public:
        Iterator(node<T>* u) {
            v = u;
        }

        T& operator*() {
            return v->element; 
        }
        friend class LinkedList<T>;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList{
    public:
        node<T>* head;
        node<T>* tail;
}; // remember the closing semi colon
```